# How to read a matrix into R using tidyverse tools?

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse, tibble, readr

Could you please help me?

I frequently need to read **incidence matrices** (AxB) into `R` formatted as **TXT** files. They look like this:

```
matrix <- matrix(round(runif(50, 0, 100),0), 5, 10)
```

My usual solution involves base's `read.delim` and `as.matrix`:

```
as.matrix(read.delim("matrix.txt", row.names = 1))
```

The file is read and converted to `matrix` class, so the proper analyses can be carried out.

However, I would like to be able to read a matrix file also using **tidyverse's** `read_delim`, so the reading process can be faster for large matrices or a large number of matrices. I've tried this:

```
as.matrix(read_delim("matrix.txt", delim = "/t"))
```

But the data get scrambled in a very strange format, and the information is lost. Is there a way to read and work with incidence `matrices` using **tidyverse** tools?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, you need to use backslash to denote the special and escape characters.

Try

```
as.matrix(read_delim("matrix.txt", delim = "\t"))
```

The `read_delim` function does not have a row.names option, so you will have to transform the data to get your rownames as rownames (and not the first column). You should do this before you convert to matrix.

```
library(tidyverse)
matrix <- read_delim("matrix.txt", delim = "\t") %>%
  column_to_rownames(first_column) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly. Nevertheless, there is something odd. I tested both solutions, read.delim and read_delim, with microbenchmark, and the tidyverse one is evaluating much slower. Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
as.matrix(read_delim("matrix.txt", delim = "\t", col_names = F))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It looks like the result gets closer to a matrix format, when col_names = T.